Can biological father be found using Paternal matches with 81cM or less?
I've  been trying to find my biological father for 5 years now on ancestry. I have also uploaded my DNA to all the other sites that I possibly could, to no avail. my mother refuses to give me any information and so I have zero clues to go on. The closest match found on my paternal side is a female on Ancestry with a predicted relationship:

4th cousin
1% Shared DNA, 81cM across 7 segments.

How can I determine who my father is with such low cM counts?

With such low centimorgan (cM) counts and a distant match, identifying your biological father can be challenging but not impossible. Here’s what you can try:

Build Out the Tree of the 4th Cousin Match: Even though the match is distant, start by building out that cousin's family tree. Look for any common surnames, regions, or patterns that might give you clues about shared ancestors. Since you're related around the 4th cousin level, you could share great-great-great-grandparents, so trace the cousin's tree upward and downward as much as you can.

Cluster Matching and DNA Painter: Use tools like Ancestry’s "ThruLines" or third-party tools like GEDmatch’s "DNA Painter" to help cluster your matches into groups that share common ancestors. By grouping these clusters, you might identify patterns or branches in the family tree that can help narrow down your paternal lineage.

Focus on Shared Matches: Look at the shared matches you have with the 4th cousin. Even if these matches are also distant, they may provide additional clues. Try to cluster these matches into smaller groups that might represent a particular family line. Compare the trees of those shared matches to see if any common ancestors or locations emerge.

Explore Other Sites: Keep checking new matches on Ancestry, 23andMe, MyHeritage, GEDmatch, etc. The databases are constantly growing, so you might find a closer match in the future.

Consider Professional Help: If you've been at this for 5 years without much success, you might consider hiring a genetic genealogist. These professionals are skilled in working with limited data and can help you triangulate your results or explore further avenues.

Investigate Family History: Even without direct information from your mother, you might still try to gather clues from family history, friends, or even public records like birth certificates, voter rolls, or social security applications that might point to potential candidates.


The process can be slow, but by continuing to build out your tree and working with what small connections you have, you might eventually uncover more about your biological father.

AI generated garbage.

Agreed. Also, DNAPainter isn't a GEDmatch tool, it's a website with its own tools, including WATO, apparently what's being referred to here. WATO won't work with a single sample, unless it's the target's parent, child, or sibling.

There is a unique potential solution which I have used before with great success. The concept works as such: If a person is looking for a biological parent, and they can get the known parent to do an Autosomal DNA test (via Ancestry, 23andMe, MyHeritage or FTDNA's Family Finder), if permission is given for the parent's result to be shared on Gedmatch, there is a "phasing" type tool in which one submits their DNA result plus the DNA result of the known parent. This tool essentially does a "Process of Elimination" in which DNA that does not represent the person and known parent, represents the missing parent. So, if you could persuade your mother to test and follow through, you would be able to obtain a "pseudo" DNA kit for your biological father. I did this for my step-dad using my Mom's DNA kit, and my half-brother's kit, and the result was a quite decent "pseudo" DNA kit representing my deceased step-dad. I have checked a number of matches and they do line up. This is an amazing tool via Gedmatch which is often either not known, or overlooked, but it does work and is the next best thing to not being able to test an unknown parent.
